# Algorithmic Analysis of Insertion Sort case

Tags: algorithm, sorting, asymptotic-complexity, insertion-sort

[image]

I'm studying for an exam I have tomorrow and I can't seem to understand this problem. (This is an old assignment that I already have the answers to). I don't quite understand parts b and parts c.

I understand that b will be a reverse sorted list, but I don't understand how to find the number of comparisons. The answer if the summation k from 1 to (n/2) of 2(2k-1) which = (n^2)/2 - 1. Why are we only summing from 1 to n/2 and not n? What difference does it make that the values are twice? wouldn't we still need to iterate through them all?

I'm confused on c as well. How would we go about finding this? I really am not sure how to find average cases.

EDIT: 
Ok. I sort of understand b now. Since it's the worst case input you know the equal numbers are going to be next to each other. So the odd indexes do i comparisons while the even indexes do i-1 since there's always going to be itself in the already sorted portion.

Still clueless with c still :/.

Please, any elaboration and explanations would be forever grateful.